# Access Storage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS (Root/Download Folder To View a file)

Tags: java, android

This Method is Not Working To Read a Downloaded File

```
File localFile = new File(Storage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + downloadableFileName);
```

Nor this also Working

```
File localFile = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + downloadableFileName);
```

Files Are Downloaded to Root/Download folder Not to App Specific Folder

Can Any One Help

The Download Method is

```
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String fileUrl = strings[0];   // -> http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/maven.pdf
        String filename = strings[1];
        String extStorageDirectory = Storage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS;

        File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory);
        folder.mkdir();
        initClipboardDownloadListener(filename);
        Downloader request = Downloader.getInstance(getActivity())
                .setListener(downloadListener)
                .setUrl(fileUrl)
                .setToken(fileUrl)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
                .setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true)
                .setDescription("Downloading....")
                .setKeptAllDownload(true)
                .setScanningByMediaScanner(false)
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setDestinationDir(extStorageDirectory, filename)
                .setNotificationTitle(filename);
        request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
        request.start();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please tell the used values of file.getAbsolutePath(). After that tell what you mean with Root as there is no such path in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"/Download/" + fileName;
File file = new File(path);
...
```

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() deprecated in API level 29 java

Comment: Is there any Other Method, Will help me a lot.

Comment: Yes there is. Try getExternalFilesDir(), getExternalCacheDir(), or getExternalMediaDir().

Comment: getExternalFilesDir() takes it to App Specific Folder like Android>data>appname>example

Comment: Storage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS How to access this Root>Downloads

Comment: You can get download folder like this:
getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

Comment: also you can add .path to get the path in string.

Comment: getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) this will Access The App Specific Folder . Tested this method not Working , i Want To access root /Downloads